# Any good ways of quickly auditing code in a source control compared to production?

Tags: sql, business-intelligence, audit

The company I work for has recently made a new IT division. With this new IT division we wanted to do a full audit of all the current code we have out in our source control but with a few thousand projects for Business Intelligence alone manual process of looking at the source control code and comparing it to production would be an extremely long process. Does anyone know of a good way of auditing code and comparing the source control code to production in a fast, efficient process?

The majority of this code are SSRS, SSIS, and other Business Intelligence Related projects if that makes a difference.

Comment: Using KDiff is out of the question?

Answer (score 3):

Since SSRS and SSIS are XML files, you could compare the text with the source code.  It sounds like you might need to create your own custom code to compare.

Some questions I would have when doing something like this:

- Are the production files in a similar folder structure to the source code?
- Is there a standard naming convention for files?
- Is a source file's name unique?

In .net you can do some file comparison, if you need difference sets, you might look for a tool/library you could use.